# react native and flask api network request failed

Tags: api, react-native, flask

I've built a simple api using Flask and a react native front end. I am running both of these on separate ports on my computer. The flask api works properly and can be accessed inside a browser. When I run:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
.then((responseJson) => {
  callback(responseJson);
})
```

I get an error on my android device of "Network request failed". Has anyone experiences this problem before? I have seen other have experienced similar problems but I could not find a solution online. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your IP instead of 127.0.0.1. It should work.

More details here:
[How can I access my localhost through Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332033/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-through-android-phone)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute `adb reverse` first to connect to your development server. Run the following command.

```
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a while, and even putting my IP address didn't work. I figured out that in addition to using your IP address, you need to configure Flask to run on your machine's IP address. You can do it like this:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This worked for me.